# Replace string in a model with another model value

Tags: angularjs

I need to use a model value within another model value, let me show you a sample.

I'm building a "tutorial" app that use a JSON file to configurated all the questions/answers something like this.

```
...
"courses": [
    "lessons": [
        "questions": [
            {  
                "id": "uniqueIdOne",
                "question": "What is your name?",
                "answer" : ""
            },
            {
                "id": "uniqueIdTwo",
                "question": "Great {{uniqueIdOne}}, this is some random text.",
                "answer": ""
            }
        ]
    ]
]
...
```

What I need, is a way to give the tutorial editor the ability to use previous answers in another questions {{uniqueIdOne}} like the sample.

There is a way in angular to do that? or should I create a filter to parse the string and loop the JSON file until I find the according id and then replace the text in the old way?

Right now, the app renders input files according with the questions to get the user answers mapped with the according model.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question may be a bit easier to visualize and answer if you provide a bit of the code you are currently using to render this JSON data.  You might review http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for tips on how to make your samples easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and there are multiple ways of accomplishing the same thing.

Assuming you have a controller set with `ng-controller`:

```
$scope.questions =  [
            {  
                "id": "uniqueIdOne",
                "question": "What is your name?",
                "answer" : ""
            },
            {
                "id": "uniqueIdTwo",
                "question": "Great <answer question-id="uniqueIdOne" questions="questions"></answer>, this is some random text.",
                "answer": ""
            }
        ];

module.directive('answer', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            questions: '=',
            questionId: '=' 
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<span class="answer">{{ answer }}</span>',
        link: function($scope) {
            var question = _.find($scope.questions, {id: $scope.questionId});
            if(question) {
                $scope.answer = question.answer;
            }
        }  
    }; 
});
```

Where `_.find` is [lodash.find](https://lodash.com/docs#find)

Now you'll need to make sure you [bind HTML](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) when you display questions so that the directives (`answer` we just defined) inside them are parsed by AngularJS.

So:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <span ng-bind-html="question.question"></span> 
</div>
```